# Remove orphan identities in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am in the process of moving a TFS 2010 installation from one machine to another.

I found that is possible remap identities using `TFSConfig Identities /change` command but I didn't find a way to remove orphan user identities that I don't need anymore.

I know that probably I can leave them there, but I am fussy and I like keeping things in order. Do you have any idea how to safely remove unused identities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't clean them up. They are inactive so think of them as tombstones. If you get rid of them, you may experience dangling users (in Access Control Entries or File History for example).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as is typical with many Microsoft products, the application is lacking many useful features (like a function to delete identities).  You can do what I did and manually remove entries from the TFS_Configuration database in the table `tbl_security_identity_cache` and it will clean them up.

You will have to temporarily disable the foreign key constraints on the table or else you can't delete from it.

I used a statement like:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_security_identity_cache
WHERE 'display_name' IN
(
    'useless crummy identity 1',
    'useless messy identity 2'
)
```

and so on

When I searched for how to do this nobody had posted it so here you go.

Comment: I would really caution against directly deleting data from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

After doing an upgrade to TFS2012 from TFS2010 that was converted from TFS2008 we have a lot of unneeded identities.  The problem is when I do a

```
tf workspaces /owner:* /collection:%TFB_COLL_12%
```

I don't get anything but

```
TF14045: The identity <GUID> is not a recognized identity.
```

Doing a specific current user, it lists the workspaces.

So while I understand the need to keep old users since they may have changes, the tf workspaces command shouldn't give such an ugly message.

Comment: Not sure this is an answer to the question.  Seems more like a comment on Remi's answer or the original question.