# Cannot remove orphan users in tfs 2015 update 3

Tags: tfs-2015

I have migrated TFS 2013 to TFS 2015 update 3, and also from DOMAIN (Domain1--> Domain2). After that some legacy users from Domain1 appeared in the new TFS 2015.

I can go to TFS Administrator Console, and try to remove them, but is not working. It says, Malformed Artifact URI....

Any workaround available ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docs say doing a move plus moving domains is unsupported https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This is 2013, I have moved to TFS 2015.

Comment: If you go to the latest docs pages https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/get-started it still points to that page. They don't support upgrading both of those things at the same time. I think you need to do the domain move first or the upgrade first, then the domain move. If you search around SO you'll see that TFS and orphan users are a general problem during upgrades no matter what

Comment: Ok, now is done, any workarround available? Deleting them from the database?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to use TFSSecurity.exe as @Cece - MSFT mentioned in the other answer to see if you can remove them from there. The DB method mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042666/remove-orphan-identities-in-tfs-2010 will invalidate your support from MS

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [TFSConfig Identities](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#identities) command to change the security identifier (SID) of users:

```
TFSConfig Identities [/change /fromdomain:DomainName1 /todomain:DomainName2 [/account:AccountName]
```

Comment: domain1, is a workgroup (local server users) and domain 2 is a domain controller. Old TFS is not powered anymore. What this domain move does exactly?

Comment: You don't need these accounts any more? You should have removed them before changing the environment. You may check tfssecurity /g- command to see whether it can remove these accounts: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#g-remove-a-user-or-group